Pandas Dataframe ffill with Previous Nonzero value in groups
Asked a very similar question earlier that got a good answer, but realized that there's more to it. I have a dataframe like:
      LOT_ID           STEP_NUMBER
0     4258556          0.0
1     4258556          0.0
2     4258556          1.0
3     4258556          1.0
4     4258556          2.0
5     4258556          2.0
6     4258556          3.0
7     4258556          3.0
8     4258556          4.0
9     4258556          5.0
10    4258556          5.0
11    4258556          6.0
12    4258556          6.0
13    4258556          7.0
14    4258556          7.0
15    4258556          0.0
16    4261512          0.0
17    4261512          1.0
18    4261512          1.0
19    4261512          2.0
20    4261512          2.0
21    4261512          3.0
22    4261512          3.0
23    4261512          4.0
24    4261512          5.0
25    4261512          5.0
26    4261512          6.0
27    4261512          6.0
28    4261512          7.0
29    4261512          7.0
30    4261512          0.0
31    4265282          0.0
32    4265282          1.0
33    4265282          1.0
34    4265282          2.0
35    4265282          2.0
36    4265282          3.0
37    4265282          3.0
38    4265282          4.0
39    4265282          4.0
40    4265282          5.0
41    4265282          5.0
42    4265282          6.0
43    4265282          7.0
44    4265282          7.0
45    4265282          0.0
46    4265706          0.0
47    4265706          1.0
48    4265706          1.0

I want to ffill the trailing zeros in step_number for each lot_id group with one greater than the previous, non-zero value to give:
    LOT_ID           STEP_NUMBER
0     4258556          0.0
1     4258556          0.0
2     4258556          1.0
3     4258556          1.0
4     4258556          2.0
5     4258556          2.0
6     4258556          3.0
7     4258556          3.0
8     4258556          4.0
9     4258556          5.0
10    4258556          5.0
11    4258556          6.0
12    4258556          6.0
13    4258556          7.0
14    4258556          7.0
15    4258556          8.0
16    4261512          0.0
17    4261512          1.0
18    4261512          1.0
19    4261512          2.0
20    4261512          2.0
21    4261512          3.0
22    4261512          3.0
23    4261512          4.0
24    4261512          5.0
25    4261512          5.0
26    4261512          6.0
27    4261512          6.0
28    4261512          7.0
29    4261512          7.0
30    4261512          8.0
31    4265282          0.0
32    4265282          1.0
33    4265282          1.0
34    4265282          2.0
35    4265282          2.0
36    4265282          3.0
37    4265282          3.0
38    4265282          4.0
39    4265282          4.0
40    4265282          5.0
41    4265282          5.0
42    4265282          6.0
43    4265282          7.0
44    4265282          7.0
45    4265282          8.0
46    4265706          0.0
47    4265706          1.0
48    4265706          1.0

How can I do this? The question that I posed before assumed it was only trailing zeros in a column that would need to be replaced. But there are a number of groups with trailing zeros that require replacement.

From a glance, it looks like you just need to use .groupby().apply(). Do you know how to do that?

Yes, but how do I ffill one greater then the previous non-zero value from that?

mozway already posted the code to do that on the previous question. You just need to adapt it to .apply().

My brother in Christ, I've been trying to. Can you help me out?

df['out'] = df.groupby('LOT_ID')['STEP_NUMBER'].transform(lambda x: x.mask(x.eq(0)[::-1].cummin(), x.max()+1))

Closing the question since it's almost the same. I'll add a note to the other answer.

Mozway, you are a golden god
